# What is the difference between Sharepoint Designer and Designer Manager in SP2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

Could someone point out the differences between Sharepoint Designer and the new Design Manager within Sharepoint 2013 ? I searched on the web but haven't found a concrete answer.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

1) SPD can still be used to edit SharePoint pages, but the visual Design view and Split view were removed so you need to do all your editing in a code view.  You can also still use it for the other things you mentioned.

2) Design Manager is free and included with SharePoint Server.  It only works on Publishing sites so its not included with Foundation.

3) Its part of the base installation of the product.  You don't need to do anything to procure it.

4) Not really.  Design manager provides functionality for Importing/Exporting HTML and CSS that can be edited in any Web Design platform.  For example Dream Weaver.  Since SPD no longer has a WYSIWYG editor there is not real connection between the two.

5) Most of the customization you've already done will be brought across when you do a content database upgrade.  I'm sure there will be some things that need to be upgraded after you do the database attach.